# Would one expect Canadair CL-215 or CL-415 planes to be equipped with a working ADS-B transpoder?

Tags: ads-b, firefighting

In a forrest fire in Greece, on which according to news sources eight such planes are operating as firefighters, [no planes can be seen on Flightradar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/37.97,23.06/11#).  Only a fire service's helicopter can be seen flying around.

Note that the planes in question are operated by the [Hellenic Air Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenic_Air_Force).

[image: Fire service helicopter path]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Military operators can request that their aircraft are not shown on flightradar24.

> Operators of private or sensitive aircraft may request their tracking details be restricted or not displayed. Generally, aircraft requesting that they not be displayed on Flightradar24 are military aircraft.

From: https://www.flightradar24.com/blog/whats-this-plane-doing-answering-recent-frequently-asked-questions/

Whether or not an airplane is equipped with ADS-B is entirely up to the operator. Both the CL-215 and CL-415 were designed before ADS-B existed. However, if the mission demands it, ADS-B capabilities may be retrofitted to existing aircraft. Whether this is the case for these particular Canadairs, I do not know (I expect not), but regardless, it's impossible to make any definite conclusions based on the absence on FR24 and related tracking websites.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Greece requires ADS-B, but even if there was such a requirement, it's unsurprising that you wouldn't be able to see military aircraft on FR24. Operators, private or public, can request that their aircraft not be shown, typically for privacy reasons or operational security. Celebrities sometimes do this, and combat aircraft are not seen. Using PlaneFinder, one can often see US transport, tanker, and sometimes trainer and flight test aircraft. You never see bombers, attack aircraft, fighters, or those otherwise engaged in sensitive operations. You can often see the same in the UK, and even sometimes fighters from the RAF if you know where to look and what to look for. I don't know specifically if the Hellenic Air Force has requested that their aircraft (if ADS-B equipped) be blocked, but it would absolutely not be surprising. The lack of the aircraft on ADS-B sites such as FR24 is unsurprising and may be an indicator of a few different things, so it's hard to draw a conclusion based simply on the lack of publicly-available tracking data.